# update a column of a table row sql 3

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, stored-procedures, sql-update

http://upload7.ir/images/38494239720146662835.png

In this picture I want to read the first line by a query and change the HASDATA to the 1 or true(for first line) but all the hasdata in all lines changes to true.

I used this code and it works, but when this code run in a while ring query still working on the same line. I want to run query in the next line when code is runing in a while ring.

Here is my stored procedure code:

```
ALTER procedure [dbo].[selecfirstvalue] (@ParentId int,@CrawlerCheck bigint)
as
update TBLCrowler set ParentId=@ParentId , CrawlerCheck=@CrawlerCheck , HasData=1 
where CatId=(Select min(CatId) from TBLCrowler)
end
```

Comment: Your where clause will always pickup the same record, the record with the lowest CatId

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
ALTER procedure [dbo].[selecfirstvalue] (@ParentId int,@CrawlerCheck bigint)
as
update TBLCrowler set ParentId=@ParentId , CrawlerCheck=@CrawlerCheck , HasData=1 
where CatId=(Select min(CatId) from TBLCrowler where HasData=0)
end
```